how to return from a function call with return value in c++?
In the below function, I want to check if the dynamic memory allocation is successful with the if statement and the return to exit the function when the allocation is failed. But when I run this code, there is error about the return. Should I add something behind the return?
I tried return -1 and return 0, but it did not work. And I think it's a thing of c++, I want to know what should I add behind the return?
typedef struct Lnode {
    int data;
    struct Lnode* next;
}Lnode, * List;

List InitList() {
    Lnode* head = new Lnode;
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "Initialization Allocation Failed!\n";
        return;
    }

    head->data = -1;
    head->next = NULL;

    return head;
}


You need to return a List because that's what the function is declared to return. Since it's a pointer returning nullptr is a good option.

Yes.  Your function must ALWAYS return a List.  Perhaps you should return nullptr in that case.  return 0; should have worked as well.

A side note: in practice new will never return null. See: Why doesn't new in C++ return NULL on failure.

You must return a Lnode*. It is very doubtful that return 0; didn't work.

A couple of unrelated things: In C++ you don't need typedef for structures; You should try to split up lists into separate "list" and "node" structures; And NULL is a C backward compatibility macro, in C++ you should use nullptr. It seems you're learning C and not C++.

On another side note, type aliasing pointers usually leads to mysterious problems.

Side note: this kind of construct typedef struct Foo{} AliasObj, *AliasPtr; is asking for a prize in ioccc.

You should read the chapter about exceptions in your C++ textbook. You don't need the error handling there at all !

Note: that is NOT the kind of code you should be using in C++ anyway. If you want a list use a std::list. So whoever is teaching you C++ is already doing a bad job

You are wasting your time new never returns NULL. If it fails it throws an exception, it doesn't return.

This is C++ code written in a C style. Whoever is teaching you C++ does not know what they are doing.

I am pretty sure you asked the exact same question some days ago. I don't have enough rep to see deleted questions to verify my assumption, but please don't do that. If a question is deleted, it is because of its very low quality. Asking again will not enhance the question.

Your function is declared to return a List, so it must return an object of that type in every return statement.
Since List is actually a pointer type, returning a nullptr is a reasonable option to return an invalid/empty List. So you need to change return to e.g. return nullptr;. Note that the caller will need to check this return value to make sure the function succeeded.
A few notes:

The standard new will not return a null pointer if allocation failed. Instead it will throw an exception. See more info here: Why doesn't new in C++ return NULL on failure.

In modern C++ it is better to use the pointer literal nullptr, instead of NULL which is traditionally a preprocessor #define to 0.

You don't need a typedef in C++ to define a struct type. struct Lnode { ... }; will do just fine. You also don't really need to define a type for a pointer to Lnode, but if you insist better do it in a separate typedef or using statement.


